# How to add properties to compiled dll file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm compiling some `dll` file and I'd like to make it possible to see what the file is in the properties tab. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: image description]

I translated some fields for clarity. I do often use this tab to try to find details about program or DLL file. So I'd like to add the following:

- Short description what it is (**`Popis souboru`** = `File description`)
- URL of the source code/project home
- Long description that can be seen in a text field?

As I suppose this depends on compiler: I'm using the default bundled compiler for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Have a look at the Version Information in your resource file, it has sections for different languages.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem tu support the most important thing - DLL description. DLL description is also displayed by most DLL injection tools allowing the user to easily find what he's looking for.

Comment: Adding properties is pretty simple, the hard problem to solve is to get Windows to display them.  Writing and debugging a property sheet extension handler is a couple of weeks of your life you'll never get back.  [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant I think you have misunderstood. I'm solely trying to add the information that is displayed in the tab on the screenshot. You're talking about modifying some system shell stuff.

Comment: Oh.  Well, just edit the VERSION resource and don't leave anything blank.  You can map it to the localized property names from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, select View | Resource View.  If your application does not have a Version resource, right click on your application.rc file in the tree and select Add Resource.  Select Version from the list that pops up.  Then you can edit it in a window similar to:

[image]

Comment: It throws error that `afxres.h` doesn't exist, whatever it is supposed to be. I get errors in that order: [A](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lt498.png), [B](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kdbvz.png). Final product is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9rCkg.png

Comment: Is your application MFC?  The afxres.h refers to an MFC include file.  If not, open your .rc file in Notepad and remove this reference, and try again.  But you can edit other resources in your project, right?

Comment: I managed to remove that file refference and I also had to add include for `<windows.h>` to get it to compile. Otherwise it works perfectly, thanks! :)

Comment: But for some reason, company name does not display in properties when I compile...

Comment: You can open your .dll in Visual Studio and view its resources. Make sure the company name is in the version resource. Also the version resource can contain different info for different languages. Maybe Windows is showing a different language's version strings.

Comment: It's actually quite broken. I defined several languages (English, czech, french) but after compiling, only one adn the very same was visible on different locales (tested in Win7-Czech and WinXP-English). Company name displays properly in applications that want to display it but is not shown in properties. According to my googling, it just isn't designed to display there. Resource hacker displayed something that seemed rather broken and didn't correspond to what I've seen in file properties.

Comment: FWIW, Company Name doesn't show up for my apps either in US English.  That is OK because I put the company into the Copyright.  ;)